# Python Proper JSON Format

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I need to post data to a REST API. One field, `incident_type`, needs to be passed in the below JSON format ( must include brackets, can't be just curly brackets ):

```
"incident_type_ids": [{
    "name": "Phishing - General"
}],
```

When I try to force this in my code, it doesn't come out quite right. There will usually be some extra quote-escapes ( ex. output: `"incident_type_ids": "[\\"{ name : Phishing - General }\\"]"`)and I realized that was because I was double-encoding the JSON data in the `incident type` variable to forcibly add the brackets ( in line 6 which has since been commented out ):

```
#incident variables
name = 'Incident Name 2'
description = 'This is the description'
corpID = 'id'
incident_type = '{ name : Phishing - General }'
#incident_type = json.dumps([incident_type])
incident_owner = 'Security Operations Center'

payload = {
        'name':name,
        'discovered_date':'0',
        'owner_id':incident_owner,
        'description':description,
        'exposure_individual_name':corpID,
        'incident_type_ids':incident_type
    }
body=json.dumps(payload)
create = s.post(url, data=body, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

However since I commented out the line, I can't get `incident_type` in the format I need ( with brackets ).

So, my question is: How can I get the `incident_type` variable in the proper format in the final `payload`?

Input I manually got to work using product's interactive REST API:

```
{
"name": "Incident Name 2",
"incident_type_ids": [{
    "name": "Phishing - General"
}],
"description": "This is the description",
"discovered_date": "0",
"exposure_individual_name": "id",
"owner_id": "Security Operations Center"
}
```

I figure my approach is wrong and I'd appreciate any help. I'm new to Python so I'm expecting this is a beginner's mistake.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You already figured out that you have to create a full Python object and convert it to JSON at once. But you did not apply that to `incident_type` which is still a string. Make it a dictionary!

Comment: @KlausD. When I make it into a dictionary, I still receive the variable without brackets: `"incident_type_ids": {"name": "Phishing - General"}`

Comment: It needs to be a list of dictionaries.

Comment: JSON brackets = Python lists. JSON braces = Python dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON square brackets are for arrays, which correspond to Python lists. JSON curly braces are for objects, which correspond to Python dictionaries.

So you need to create a list containing a dictionary, then convert that to JSON.

```
incident_type = [{"name": "Phishing - General"}]
incident_owner = 'Security Operations Center'

payload = {
        'name':name,
        'discovered_date':'0',
        'owner_id':incident_owner,
        'description':description,
        'exposure_individual_name':corpID,
        'incident_type_ids':incident_type
    }
body=json.dumps(payload)
```

It's only slightly coincidental that the Python syntax for this is similar to the JSON syntax.